# How to set Hibernate Configuration properties to connect to Mysql using Fabric driver

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, mysql-fabric

I'm trying to get some old code working thats creates some tables for a hibernate configuration in a Mysql Database, but the code referred to a datasource config that I no longer have and I just want to run it as standalone Java (not within Tomcat container) so Ive made some changes to Hibernate config.

My pom now includes

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>
```

My code is

```
  public static  Configuration setupDatabase()
{
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
            .setProperty(Environment.URL,"jdbc:mysql:songkong")
            .setProperty(Environment.DRIVER,"com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver")
            .setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect")
            .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username","dbuser")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "dbpassword");;
    addEntitiesToConfig(cfg);
    cfg.setProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create-drop");
    return cfg;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Configuration cfg = setupDatabase();
    new SchemaExport(cfg).create(false,true);
}
```

Currently the problem is it cant find the driver.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:songkong
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:173)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.java:55)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseExporter.<init>(DatabaseExporter.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:368)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:305)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:294)
        at com.jthink.songkong.appserverdb.util.Db.main(Db.java:143)
```

The Fabric driver is in the jar but Im not sure if I should be using this driver, and if the Environment.DRIVER line is set correctly to refer to it. I don't think I used this driver before ( a couple of years ago) but it was the only one i could find in maven central.

(My database is called songkong and i can correct to it correctly from commandline, I don't show real username and password in code excerpt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just noticed that the non-fabric driver was also in the jar, setting ENVIRONMENT.DRIVER to this and some modifications to Environment.URL fixed it.

```
 Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
                .setProperty(Environment.URL,"jdbc:mysql://localhost/songkong")
                .setProperty(Environment.DRIVER,"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                .setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect")
                .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true")
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username","dbuser")
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "dbpassword");;
```